# Documenting RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, documentation, spring-rabbit

What's the best way to document RabbitMQ (for message payload and headers) on a project?

Our project uses RabbitMQ with a complex structure of payload and headers and names of queues and I need to document all this.

I have not found any useful advice on this topic on the Internet, because this topic is little described.

Please advise a framework or a list of best practices for writing documentation for RabbitMQ.

I wanted to use spring-restdocs, but it doesn't support [that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/373).

Comment: Fully unclear what are you talking about. Why regular JavaDocs for those types are not enough for you? See also https://spring.io/projects/spring-restdocs - maybe that one will give you some clue how to be...

Comment: 1. AMQP and HTTP is pretty different things.
2. How documentate message headers?
3. spring-restdocs not'support this, see [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/373)

Answer (score 0):

I think JavaDocs can be used for the same. Also, it's simpler to implement and use.